# External JavaScript file is not getting added when running on Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, external

I have an HTML file named `showMap.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Map</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="showPosition()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And another JavaScript file `map.js` is placed in the `js` folder of the same directory.

This code works fine when the HTML file is loaded, but this does not work when I run it in the server.

I use Python's Flask framework for back-end programming and the funny thing is that the same thing will work well if I expand the JavaScript code inside the HTML file. The only problem is with the external file.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Serve the `map.js` file as a [static resource](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files):

- move the file to a `static/` subdirectory of your package
- generate a static URL for it in a Jinja2 template like so:

  ```html
   <script type="text/javascript"
           src="{{ url_for('static', filename='map.js') }}"></script>
  ```

The `filename` parameter takes a relative path; you can use subdirectories was needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is Flask only able to import from static subdirectory? I had made a directory on the same level as static and put my js file inside which chrome was not successful in import. However, when I moved the directory into static, it was successfully imported. Maybe if this behaviour is true, can it should highlighted and explained.

Comment: @seokhoonlee: `Flask` creates a special route for `/static`, which serves anything under the `static` directory, as [documented in the quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files). If you need to serve data from more directories, you'd need to create more such views (how exactly is too long to explain in a comment).

Answer (score 16):

**Step 1:**
Create folder with name static on project root

**Step 2:**
Add static files in static folder

**Step 3**
Add in template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'hello.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue, for stylesheet, the URL_FOR works but for javascript.
I had to write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/map.js"/>
```

It worked for me

Comment: This would only work for routes that use, at most, a single slash. For routes with multiple components (e.g. `/foo/bar/baz`) your relative path will resolve to a non-existing URL. It’ll also break when mounting your Flask app as a WSGI component under a base url with a path component. Don’t hardcore the static path, use the `url_for()` utility and have Flask generate the correct path for you.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add to Martijn's answer, that you have to link your js file exactly like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='map.js') }}"></script>`

and not like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='map.js') }}"/>`

Comment: That’s how the HTML `<script>` tag works, yes. My answer has always used the first form, `<script>` can’t be used as an empty tag. Note that that’s not specific to Flask.