# Server cannot locate javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to run a function from my javascript code, I have called linked the js function in my file

This is my structure:

```
project
   static
      css
        /main.css
      js
        /script.js
   templates
        /layout.html
```

This is what I have tried, placing it in my head tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}" ></script>
```

If I try `filename ='js/script.js'` - and specific the folder, neither works

My error in the js console is:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://127.0.0.1:5000/js/script.js**

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Try src="static/js/script.js" @Dennis does this work ?

Comment: @MRDR I have just tried, <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/script.js" ></script> but unfortunately that did not work either and the same error appears. I am using Flask.

Comment: try to look for similar answers here it will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711552/external-javascript-file-is-not-getting-added-when-running-on-flask

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}
```

Comment: Please see question I have already tried this and didn't work either