# Static resource problem referencing .js file in html using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

When opened directly, my html file will load my OpenLayers JavaScript file (which loads a map frame). However when I run the html from my Flask python app, the JavaScript file/object doesn't load (no map showing, just some heading text).

This issue appears to be sorted here:

[External JavaScript file is not getting added when running on Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711552/external-javascript-file-is-not-getting-added-when-running-on-flask)

However due to my folder structure, I can't seem to get the .js to load. No errors, just no map loading in the page. I think I need some help with the syntax of the 'static' reference. I think this is the issue, however I am very new to website building. This is my project folder structure:

```
ol_app.py
/pages
    olquickstart.html
/static
    /scripts
        ol_script.js
/libs
    /v6.3.1-dist
        ol.css
        ol.css.map
        ol.js
        ol.js.map
```

My Flask python app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
import webbrowser
from threading import Timer

template_dir = os.path.abspath(r'D:\PathToProject\ol_quickstart\pages')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)

#home page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/ol_qs">OL QuickStart</a>'

#openlayers test page
@app.route('/ol_qs')
def ol_qs():
    return render_template("olquickstart.html")

#run app
def open_browser():
    webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Timer(1, open_browser).start();
    app.run(port=5000)
```

my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/v6.3.1-dist/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 900px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="../libs/v6.3.1-dist/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers Quickstart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>OL Quickstart Map</h2>
    <div id="js-map" class="map"></div>
    <!-- <script src='../static/scripts/ol_script.js'></script> I USE THIS LINE WHEN OPENING THE HTML DIRECTLY WITHOUT FLASK-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/ol_script.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this part the problem?

`<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/ol_script.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: Your server can handle **MIME** outputs (Origin,Filesize,)?  Add an internal **File Creator Script** for this but dont link file object(will be duplicate more than one time). Your server  default output type is  `text/html`.

Comment: @dsgdfg sorry not sure I understand what mime is. I’m running my site from local server on my PC.

Comment: You will be want on next level.  who serve static files **and** how to manage user scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to move the `libs` directory into `static` and then include those files with similar `url_for` functions to what you already have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="{{ url_for('static', filename='libs/v6.3.1-dist/ol.css') }}">

<script type="text/javascript"
 src="{{ url_for('static', filename='libs/v6.3.1-dist/ol.js') }}"></script>
```

Your exsiting one for `scripts/ol_script.js` looks correct.

However to debug this yourself you should load the dev tools in your webbrowser and view the `Network` tab to ensure that each JS file loads sucessfully and doesn't 404.

Similarly the `Console` tab will show you any javascript errors within the page.

Comment: thanks this works! Could you explain what was going on? and why moving libs into static solved it? Also, you were missing a trailing `</script>` tag at the end of that codeblock there.

Comment: @TheoF Simply, anything provided as the `filename` arg to `url_for('static', filename='anything')` has to exist within the `static/` directory!